How to filter dataframe by column from different dataframe?
I want to filter dataframe by column with Strings from different dataframe.
val booksReadBestAuthors = userReviewsWithBooksDetails.filter(col("authors").isin(userReviewsAuthorsManyRead:_*))


  val userReviewsAuthorsManyRead = userReviewsWithBooksDetails.filter($"authors".isNotNull).groupBy(col("authors"))
                                              .agg(count("review/score").alias("count"), avg("review/score").alias("avg_score"))
                                              .filter($"avg_score" >= 4)
                                              .sort($"count".desc, $"avg_score".desc)
                                              .limit(5)
                                              .select("authors")
                                              .collect.toList.asInstanceOf[List[String]]

I want to filter the column with authors by values from userReviewsAuthorsManyRead
Authors column looks like that:
click
I am getting an error:
"The feature is not supported: literal for '[Agatha Christie]' of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema."

Just do an inner join using the Authors column, no need to collect.
As the column name is same in both dataframes, this should work:
val userReviewsAuthorsManyRead = userReviewsWithBooksDetails.filter($"authors".isNotNull).groupBy(col("authors"))
                                              .agg(count("review/score").alias("count"), avg("review/score").alias("avg_score"))
                                              .filter($"avg_score" >= 4)
                                              .sort($"count".desc, $"avg_score".desc)
                                              .limit(5)
                                              .select("authors")

userReviewsWithBooksDetails.join(userReviewsAuthorsManyRead,"authors").show

Or if you do want to use collect, the issue with your code is you are passing an entire Row as a literal, just map and get first column value as String.
val userReviewsAuthorsManyRead = userReviewsWithBooksDetails.filter($"authors".isNotNull).groupBy(col("authors"))
                                              .agg(count("review/score").alias("count"), avg("review/score").alias("avg_score"))
                                              .filter($"avg_score" >= 4)
                                              .sort($"count".desc, $"avg_score".desc)
                                              .limit(5)
                                              .select("authors")
                                              .collect
                                              .toList
                                              .map(_.getString(0))

Input:
userReviewsWithBooksDetails (Excluding other columns):
+-------+
|authors|
+-------+
|Author1|
|Author2|
|Author3|
+-------+

userReviewsAuthorsManyRead:
+-------+
|authors|
+-------+
|Author2|
|Author3|
+-------+

Output:
+-------+
|authors|
+-------+
|Author2|
|Author3|
+-------+

